# How to combine result set of two different select statement in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two different select statement but I want to show combined result in one query. I have following restriction.

1. I can't use Join because it requires at-least one common column in both statements but in my case there is no common column.
2. I can't user Union because it requires same structure of both statement and same no. of columns in both table. In my case both select statement has different structure.

Here are my two select statements.

```
select Center, SUM(PaidAmount) as TotalCollection, COUNT(Id) as TotalBills from DiagMain where 
        Cast(EntryDate as Date) = CONVERT(date, getdate()) group by Center order by Center desc
select Id, PtName, PaidAmount, DueAmount, Center, MachineName from DiagMain where Cast(EntryDate as Date) = 
        CONVERT(date, getdate()) order by Id desc
```

Please help guys...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @FelixPamittan
Actually, I don't want my application go to database two times, I want to fetch all record in just one time. It will improve performance of my application.

Comment: What language are you using in the application side? I believe you can return two `SELECT` results.

Comment: I am using Asp.Net (C#). I know I can return multiple select result fetch it through dataset. But In this case I am using jquery ajax not purely c#.
Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: You might want to include that in your question.

Comment: This is 'highly irregular', meaning no one has ever thought this was a good idea before. You can use this kind of thing: `SELECT 'TABLE1' As Tble, C1, NULL As C2 FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT  'TABLE2' As Tble, NULL , C2 FROM TABLE2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query, it seems that you want the rows from `DiagMains` along with `TotalCollection` and `TotalBills` per `Center` in the result set. If that's the case, you can use window functions `SUM() OVER` and `COUNT OVER()`:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    PtName,
    PaidAmount,
    DueAmount,
    Center,
    MachineName,
    TotalCollection = SUM(PaidAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY Center),
    TotalBIlls      = COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY Center)
FROM DiagMain
WHERE
    CAST(EntryDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no common Columns to join results, you can use Row_Number() to combine the results.

```
    SELECT Table1.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Center DESC) AS ROW, 
    Center, SUM(PaidAmount) AS Collection, COUNT(Id) AS TotalBills FROM DiagMain WHERE 
    CAST(EntryDate AS date) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) GROUP BY Center) Table1

    INNER JOIN

    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS ROW, Id,  PtName, PaidAmount, 
    DueAmount, Center, MachineName FROM DiagMain WHERE CAST(EntryDate AS date) = 
    CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) Table2 

    ON Table1.ROW = Table2.ROW
```